# How can i store recorded file to internal memory in android?

Tags: android

I am recording users voice to external memory.But In case, user is not having SD card in phone.Recorded files should get saved to internal memory.

```
static final String PREFIX = "record";
static final String EXTENSION = ".3gpp";

if (file == null) {
                File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                file = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, EXTENSION, rootDir);
            }
```

How can i save the same file to internal memory?

thanx in advance!!!!

Comment: Most of android devices has internal SD-cards, the phone will treat them as external but in fact they are built in.
You don't need to write to internal storage (System storage) in most cases, specially in multimedia cases !

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check for the availability of the external storage card. If available, then you can save the file in it. Else in phone memory.

This is how you use internal storage:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Checking availability of external storage:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

For more info check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) out

Answer (score -1):

```
  Try this:

   File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

   rootDir.mkdir();

   try {
    output=File.createTempFile(PREFIX, EXTENSION, rootDir);
} catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the phone internal storage